# Show / Hide div with input value works on Safari but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, input, safari

I'm using the below to show/hide a registration form based on the input value (i.e. a hidden registration form that you can only access with a password)...

It works fine on Safari, but not on Chrome - any ideas why?

```
<style>
#regHidden { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#ff_elem576').on('keyup', function(event) {
                        if ($(this).val() == "YANDV") 
                            $('#regHidden').show(),
                            $('#hideReg').hide();
                        else 
                            $('#regHidden').hide(),
                            $('#hideReg').show();
                });
            });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

[Here's a link](http://www.youngandviral.co.uk/register) to the page in question.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Post the full code. What is the HTML element #ff_elem576?

Comment: Guess its working in Chrome too.Please see this fiddle [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/g6onongq/)

Comment: Sorry, #ff_elem576 is an input box

Comment: It does in that fiddle, but not on my site... I can't see why... can you see here? http://www.youngandviral.co.uk/register

Comment: @MattGray:Am seeing lot of script error while loading the page you suggested.Could you please resolve that first or is there any way i could get the code ?

Comment: You should correct the errors on your page. That's probably why it isn't working. Especially the one that used the sticky function.

Comment: @MattGray:Giving errors like undefined is not a function at line 493.Thats whats it shows in console.

Comment: @Everton Lenger - thanks - I loaded the sticky function script from my own server instead of trying to access it remotely, then everything else works! Thanks... SunilHari - I'll go through the CSS and sort them out too! Thanks

Comment: @MattGray I put that as an answer, just in case.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console is showing some errors on your page. You should correct them. That's probably why it isn't working.

Especially the one that used the sticky function, that's "breaking" the JS of your page.